# Instance cloning in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am having an instance running in AWS, this instance was installed with tomcat, java,DB,  etc.,

I want to create an another instance like my running instance.

how to clone my running instance with all the installations to be available in new instance? I read about creating AMI, will it make my new instance with tomcat, java,DB, etc., installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing the **Create Image** command on an existing Amazon EC2 instance will create an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) that contains a copy of all disk volumes attached to the instance.

You can then launch a new EC2 instance from the AMI. This will result in the new instance having **exactly the same disk content**. When launching the new instance you can select a different instance type, network setting, etc -- the only part that will be identical is the content of the disk volumes.

Give it a try, it's very easy!

- Select the original instance in the **Amazon EC2 management console**
- Click Actions/Image/Create Image to **create the AMI**
- Select the new AMI in the **AMIs** section of the console
- Select the AMI, then click Actions/Launch to **launch a new instance from the AMI**

See: [Creating an Amazon EBS-Backed Linux AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create an AMI from your running instance and then launch a new instance from that AMI and it will essentially be a clone.